# select outgoing ip for curl request

Tags: php, curl, ip

I have a server with two different IPs. I need to send odd curl requests from first IP, and even from the second one. How can I select outgoing IP address?

My PHP script is something like this:

```
$curlh = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curlh, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);
curl_setopt($curlh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curlh);
```

How can I do so?

Comment: Why curl Windows does not supprt specific "--interface"?

Answer (score 59):

You may want to try setting the `CURLOPT_INTERFACE` option:

```
curl_setopt($curlh, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
```

> **CURLOPT_INTERFACE:** The name of the outgoing network interface to use. This can be an interface name, an IP address or a host name.

From: [php Manual: curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

---

**EDIT:** Fixing example, as [@Michael Hart pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425651/select-outgoing-ip-for-curl-request/4235675#4235675) pointed out in the other answer.

Answer (score 28):

Since I can't reply yet,  just wanted to add to Daniel Vassallo's answer. While he is correct, his example is not.

CURLOPT_INTERFACE is a constant, and can't be placed within quotes. This could cause a bit of confusion to some who may copy and paste only to find out that it doesn't work. The proper code would be:

```
curl_setopt($curlh, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
```

Also, for Linux systems (and I'm sure Windows, but it wont be exactly the same), I feel like pointing out that you don't have to use the IP address. If you know the ethN interface, you can simply use "eth0", "eth1", or "eth0:0" depending on how your network is configured. This may be more preferable, since the code will not be specific to 1 machine, and might fit into a more broad configuration (for example, clusters).