# Different outgoing ip using php simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, simplexml

I have two IPs on my server and I'm trying to split up my xml requests over both IP.  How can I get simplexml_load_file to make the request on different IPs?

Comment: Can you rephrase this as a question?

Comment: Thanks :) See my answer below on how to do that with cURL (choosing the request IP), then parse it with SimpleXML.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and use the [CURLOPT_INTERFACE option](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to load the XML stream. Then use [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) on the result to parse it.

See [select outgoing ip for curl request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425651/select-outgoing-ip-for-curl-request) for how to do that.