# Use other IP address of webserver

Tags: php

I have php program which I run via CLI. The aim of program is to connect some address http and get some data. Its works OK. But I want to use other IP address of my webserver instead of primary. Is there any solution for this ?

**EDIT** Webserver has multiple ip address. I want to use any of them I choose at any request. If not possible at least 1 specific one. I have tried CURL_INTERFACE, and its not sending data while i give other ip than primary

```
HOSTNAME=server.xxxx.net
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
HISTSIZE=1000
SSH_CLIENT=<my ip> 23929 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
USER=root
LS_COLORS=<blah blah>
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
PWD=/root
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
HTTP_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI=0
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
CVS_RSH=ssh
SSH_CONNECTION=<my ip> 23929 <server ip> 22
LESSOPEN=|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

**IPTable rules**

**xx.xx.xx.xx** is servers primary ip address

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [85405:31617594]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [92024:84346360]
:acctboth - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j acctboth
-A OUTPUT -j acctboth
-A acctboth -s xx.xxx.xx.xx/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80
-A acctboth -d xx.xxx.xx.xx/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80
-A acctboth -s xx.xxx.xx.xx/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25
-A acctboth -d xx.xxx.xx.xx/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25
-A acctboth -s xx.xxx.xx.xx/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110
-A acctboth -d xx.xxx.xx.xx/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110
-A acctboth -s xx.xxx.xx.xx/32 ! -i lo -p icmp
-A acctboth -d xx.xxx.xx.xx/32 ! -i lo -p icmp
-A acctboth -s xx.xxx.xx.xx/32 ! -i lo -p tcp
-A acctboth -d xx.xxx.xx.xx/32 ! -i lo -p tcp
-A acctboth -s xx.xxx.xx.xx/32 ! -i lo -p udp
-A acctboth -d xx.xxx.xx.xx/32 ! -i lo -p udp
-A acctboth -s xx.xxx.xx.xx/32 ! -i lo
-A acctboth -d xx.xxx.xx.xx/32 ! -i lo
-A acctboth ! -i lo
COMMIT
```

Comment: Depends on which web server you are using.  For IIS, yes, but you're probably not running IIS for PHP.

Comment: Do you mean your webserver has multiple IPs, and you want to use a specific one?

Comment: @EricJ. The question states that this is a CLI script, so there's no web server involved, IIS or otherwise.

Comment: Do you mean you want to select which IP address the request appears to come *from*, as seen by the remote host?

Comment: possible duplicate of [select outgoing ip for curl request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425651/select-outgoing-ip-for-curl-request)

Comment: @MarcB I have tried that version too. CURL_INTERFACE option only changes http header, which is not for real use. It still using primary ip for outgoing

Comment: Post the output of: netstat -rn

Comment: So you've got a php program that connects out to a remote host and you want to control what ip it connects out with from your box? Am i reading this right? If so, what does the program use to connect out?

Comment: @Ryven thats right. I am using CURL

Comment: Environment variables suggest proxy must be transparent. firewall rules are unhelpful since you pasted the default table. Try `sudo iptables-save` which prints all rules, in a compact form. Also do a `wget -S <destination> -O /dev/null` and look at the response headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on http server you are using , you can bind your "virtual host" configurations to specific address and port.
in Apache2 for example :

```
<VirtualHost **127.0.0.10:8080**>
     ServerAdmin myemail@mywebsite.com

     ServerName mywebsite.com
     ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
     DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm
     
     DocumentRoot /var/websites/mywebsite.com/www
     <Directory "/var/websites/mywebsite.com/www">
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog logs/mywebsite.com-error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

With nginx , something like :

```
server
{
     server_name example.com www.example.com;
     **listen 66.113.100.140:80;**
     access_log /var/log/ngnix/example.log;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/example.error.log;

location /site {
     alias /data/www/content/site/example;
}
location / {
     proxy_pass_header Server;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
     proxy_connect_timeout 10;
     proxy_read_timeout 10;
     proxy_pass http://10.15.20.10:8107/;
}
}
```

Also starting from PHP 5.4 there is [build in web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) that could be used for testing purposes. Generally you can bind to any local address as following :

```
$ cd ~/public_html
$ php -S 127.0.1.1:8000
```

Comment: Thanks for information, It was Nginx that forwarding ip. Its my weak side, i dont know nginx. Thats why i was stuck

Answer (score 1):

If you can use curl for outgoing http requests, you can set an option in curl: `CURLOPT_INTERFACE`

`curl_setopt($curlh, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");`

`**CURLOPT_INTERFACE**: The name of the outgoing network interface to use. This can be an interface name, an IP address or a host name.`

PHP Manual: [curl_setopt](http://www.php.net/curl_setopt)

Comment: Check comments first. I have tried this. Not working

Comment: In my defense, that comment was buried deep.  

Perhaps you're invoking it wrong, or something's wrong with your php/curl installation, since that option has nothing to do with HTTP, rather it touches IP two layers below.

Comment: i have tried it 3 different machine, on my local and other 2 server. While I am getting ip from $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] variable , its always servers primary address. WHile its only affecting $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']

Comment: Then you have a proxy server running somewhere along the path, most likely on the server matching REMOTE_ADDR. Those headers are added on by a proxy. Try looking at the response headers.  
CURLOPT_INTERFACE itself is working just fine.  
**This is a good example why you should supply more details.** Edit the question with your server stack details: firewall forwarding rules, environment variables like http_proxy etc. And please take back your downvote, since for the question in its current form, my answer isn't wrong.