# What is the curl option CURLOPT_INTERFACE and when to use it?

Tags: curl

From [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) the option `CURLOPT_INTERFACE` description is:

> The name of the outgoing network interface to use. This can be an
>   interface name, an IP  address or a host name.

What is meant by the outgoing network interface here in terms of computer network?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425651/select-outgoing-ip-for-curl-request

Answer (score 1):

See the cURL documentation here:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_INTERFACE.html

> Pass a char * as parameter. This sets the interface name to use as outgoing network interface. The name can be an interface name, an IP address, or a host name.

You can use this if your webserver has multiple network interfaces/ip addresses and you must select a specific interface for your request (eg your default gateway might be on your primary network interface but you need a request to go over a secondary interface).

EG You may have a request that needs to traverse a VPN.