# change curl request ip in php with amazon ec2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2, ip

I am trying to access ebay api to get information. I have three different ebay developer accounts but ebay suspends the accounts on accessing the accounts via same ip.

So I want to access each api with specific ip. I have used these techniques, but  curl request is not successful, curl_error() returns "Failed to connect to ip"

```
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_PROXY, $api_ids['ip']);
error : "failed to connect to ip"
```

and

```
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, $api_ids['ip']);
error : "bind failed with errno 99: Cannot assign requested address"
```

Moreover, I have easyhide vpn package, can I use Easyhide vpn ips in curl requests

curl request code:

```
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, $serverUrl);
//curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_PROXY, $api_ids['ip']);
//curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $api_ids['auth']);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, $api_ids['ip']);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestXmlBody);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select outgoing ip for curl request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425651/select-outgoing-ip-for-curl-request)

Comment: I have tried that, its included in the question

Comment: Well then there's just not enough information here. Does `ifconfig -a` show `$api_ids['ip']` that you're trying to bind to? How exactly is cURL failing?

Comment: curl_error() says failed to connect to ip

Comment: And this works without the `CURLOPT_INTERFACE`?

Comment: yes, it works without `CURLOPT_INTERFACE` and `CURLOPT_PROXY`

Comment: Well, don't use `CURLOPT_PROXY`, that's something different. Does it work with ONLY `CURLOPT_INTERFACE`? There is no SOCKS proxy listening on the IP you're using I'm assuming. You just need to bind to an interface.

Comment: with only `CURLOPT_INTERFACE`
it says
"bind failed with errno 99: Cannot assign requested address"