# PHP curl, special network interface

Tags: php, curl, networking, http-post, vpn

I have a (Webserver)Server with two network interfaces. The first is the standard interface with the public internet connection, the other is a virtual VPN-networkinterface.

Now I want to send POST data via curl on an other Webservice within the VPN-Network.

How I can say the php there have to call the address with the VPN-Networkinterface?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select outgoing ip for curl request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425651/select-outgoing-ip-for-curl-request)

Comment: contact your VPN provider, they are more likely to help you (it depends on the interface you are using)

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) lists CURLOPT_INTERFACE as a configurable option.

> **CURLOPT_INTERFACE** The name of the outgoing network interface to use. This can be an interface name, an IP address or a host name.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");
```